# use android tablet as ONLY display on otherwise headless server

Tags: server, android, vnc

I am new to Ubuntu and Servers in general.  I have a Lubuntu server I would like to be primarily headless, but would like to use my android tablet to remote into it when necessary instead of having to hook it up to one of my monitors.

I have tried splashtop but that seems to only duplicate an existing display.

Is there a vnc program that would accomplish what I am attempting to do? or some other means of remote access that would be able to allow me to remove all displays from my server, set it in a corner and when needed control it from my tablet?

Answer (score 0):

I access my headless box over ssh; usually from a laptop, but sometimes from my tablet using ConnectBot.

xrdp or VNC is also an option, but I found little need for it, personally.

fwiw, there are good transmission-remote clients for android, if you're into that.